# With elasticsearch version:6.4.3. I want to group by a field(type is date) with hour between some days

Tags: elasticsearch-aggregation

I want to group by start_time with hour between 20190701 and 20190710,but not each day each hour is a bucket, I want the data Divided into 24 buckets,for example: 20190701,20190801,20190901... fall into the 01 bucket,20190702,20190802,20190902... fall into the 02 bucket and so on.

this is each day each hour is a bucket,the result is not what I want,how to solve this problem?

start_time field type as follows:

```
"start_time": 
{
      "type": "date",
       "format": "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss||epoch_second"
}
```

My code as followed:

```
GET qd_analysis/kw/_search
{
  "size": 0, 
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "term": {
            "uin":   {
              "value": "111"
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "range": {
            "imp_date": {
              "gte": "20190701",
              "lte": "20190710"
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "result": {
      "date_histogram": {
        "field": "start_time",
        "time_zone": "+08:00",
        "interval": "hour",
        "format": "HH",
        "order": {
          "_count": "desc"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I want to group by start_time with hour between 20190701 and 20190710,but not each day each hour is a bucket, I want the data Divided into 24 buckets,for example: 20190701,20190801,20190901... fall into the 01 bucket,20190702,20190802,20190902... fall into the 02 bucket and so on.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use terms aggregation, with script to extract the hour-of-day:

```
{
  "aggs": {
     "hour_of_day": {
        "terms": {
           "script": "doc['@timestamp'].date.hourOfDay"
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: No,for example: 20190701 - 20190707, your code is first group by to 7 days,then second group by hour for each day; I think if possible only one aggregation , divided into 24 buckets, 0 - 23 bucket, 2019070100,2019070200...2019070700 fall into the 0 bucket ,2019070101,2019070201...2019070701 fall into the 1 bucket and so on